# What is the use of a capacitor between Vdd and Vss (or Vcc and Vee)?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, stm32, can

I'm trying to make my STM32 communicate VIA Can. Therefore I'm making use of the CAN transceiver MCP 2551. In many circuits I've seen a 100 nF between Ground and Vdd. What is the reason for that? Here an example:[image: Example schematic showing a MCP2551 with 100nF capacitor between VDD and VSS]

Comment: This is just a decoupling (bypass) cap. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/what-is-a-decoupling-capacitor-and-how-do-i-know-if-i-need-one/2278 also: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/decoupling-caps-pcb-layout/15143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a decoupling or power supply bypass capacitor.  It's used to reject noise from the supply pins of an IC.

Comment: Ok thanks! How do I determine which capacity is needed for a decoupling capacitor?

Comment: Dig around dim's links for some good suggestions and explanations if you're curious, but the most common (that I've seen) is 0.1uF.