# Does my IC have less voltage or too much noise?

Tags: voltage, noise

I’ve recently been building Ben eater’s VGA kit and for some reason most of the IC’s have glitches like the counter goes from 0000 to 1100 and nand gate goes low twice while counting from 0 till 210 and other issues. It works sometimes and other times it doesn’t. So it works inconsistently. So does it need more voltage or a capacitor to reduce noise? I’m sure the wiring is correct as I’ve build it almost 3 times and there were always different errors

[image]

Comment: Show us the schematic and pictures of your actual implementation.

Comment: I added a picture and a bit of info to the end of the text

Comment: Probably want at least a few bypass caps in there.

Comment: Put a 10nF to 100nF ceramic capacitor across each of the IC power pins near to each chip and something like 100uF/10V electrolytic on the breadboard or whatever you are using, if you don’t already have them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what’s the difference between the 2 capacitors? And how many do I need of each type? And is it surely a capacitor issue or could it be something else? And how to know where to place them? Sorry for so many questions, I’m just a bit stressed

Comment: So you don’t have any capacitors at all? In which case I can expand in a more detailed answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah I don’t have any, Ben never used any so I didn’t think I’d need them.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/what-is-a-decoupling-capacitor-and-how-do-i-know-if-i-need-one

Answer (score 2):

Bypass capacitors are almost always recommended for digital circuits. You can sometimes get away without them (as you’ve seen) depending on the type of logic, the circuit and how your layout is implemented. Typical symptoms of inadequate bypassing are glitches, erratic or incorrect operation.

The reason they are useful is that brief pulses of current are drawn whenever the logic switches- which means that any inductance in the layout will cause voltages to arise. Even a straight piece of wire or the link in your breadboard has measurable inductance. Depending on the type of logic, only a few hundred mV may be enough to affect operation. When you add a capacitor, the capacitor can supply those pulses of current.

Contrary to what is sometimes thought, you don’t need to be clocking the circuit at megahertz frequencies to see issues because brief glitches can be latched or clocked into flip-flops. Modern chips switch *fast*, hundreds of picoseconds for modern CMOS and even the LS chips switch in nanoseconds.

The standard approach is one ceramic capacitor per small scale logic chip, very close (within say 5 or 10mm) to the power pins. On more complex parts, often one or more per power pin. Close, because the traces have inductance. Ceramic because that type has more ideal behavior. Then one or more bulk storage electrolytic capacitors placed reasonably close (several inches) of the circuit. Electrolytic because they are small and cheap. Larger ceramic caps can (eg 10uF) can also be used.

These are just general considerations- if you are using very fast logic the caps should be closer- for glacially slow 5V 4000B logic it’s not as important to be close. LS as you are using is in the middle.

In your case, it’s quite possible that a single 100uF electrolytic cap across the power bus of the breadboard might work, but I would use a few more ceramic caps at least. 100nF is a good value in general. For a breadboard you can use leaded multilayer ceramic capacitors (MLCC) or disk capacitors.

Incidentally, you will sometimes see enormous numbers of bypass capacitors- literally **hundreds**- on fancy high-speed circuits such as large FPGAs, typically around the chip and mounted on the oppside of the board.

Comment: so for every IC I need a ceramic capacitor and for the breadboard 1 electrolytic capacitor? Is there an explanation on bypass capacitors on how they exactly work?

Comment: That should ensure that any problems are not as a result of inadequate bypassing. I have tried to explain above how they work without getting into math or finer details. If you would like more details in a video format, Dave Jones’ has [this](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/blog/eevblog-859-bypass-capacitor-tutorial/) that is moderately detailed. There are entire books if you want more on this and related subjects (eg. Dr. Howard Johnson).

Comment: Could I also just put one electrolytic capacitor on the rail and that’s it? Since I got that recommended by someone and you said it in your post, but That won’t guarantee that it works right?

Comment: No, it won’t guarantee anything but it will be better. :-) Adding a bit here and there until it barely works is kind of like “Muntzing” in reverse.

Comment: do you by any chance have discord? I’d like to ask some last questions before I buy the capacitors

Comment: I do not have it.

Comment: this is what I’m going to buy, 220uf electrolytic capacitor x10 and 100uf ceramic capacitor x10

Comment: I suggest 100uF/10V electrolytic and 100nF 10V ceramics. Product recommendations are off topic, but you could open another question and ask if the parts you have in mind are suitable- providing datasheet links and your circuit. Someone (likely not me at present) should answer.